# Django bulk create for non-repetitive entries

Tags: django, excel

I want to insert data from an Excel file to the database, but I want to insert only non-repetitive ones.

I wrote this code, but the `if` statement is always `False`!

```
def ca_import(request):
    uploadform=UploadFileForm(None)
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        uploadform = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if uploadform.is_valid():
            file = uploadform.cleaned_data['docfile']
            workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file, read_only=True)
            # Get name of the first sheet and then open sheet by name
            first_sheet = workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]
            worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)
            data = []
            try:

               for row in worksheet.iter_rows(row_offset=1): # Offset for header
                  stockname =StocksName()

                  if (StocksName.objects.filter(name=row[0].value).count()<1):  #???
                     stockname.name=row[0].value
                     data.append(stockname)
                     StocksName.objects.bulk_create(data)

               messages.success(request,"Successful" ,extra_tags="saveexcel")
               except :
               messages.error(request,_('Error'),extra_tags="excelerror")

    return render(request, 'BallbearingSite/excelfile.html',{'uploadform':uploadform})
```

Any suggestion to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you data has a unique id then you can use [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) or [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) instead of `bulk_create()`

Otherwise you will have to write the logic to check if each line already exists in your model.